Can't build with colcon on ROS2 Humble. Issue with empy library
I'm on Ubuntu 22 Desktop. Just installed ROS 2 Humble and can't proceed with this tutorial
https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Colcon-Tutorial.html
When I try to execute colcon build, I get this error
ERROR:colcon.colcon_core.extension_point:Exception loading extension 'colcon_core.environment_variable.powershell_command': cannot import name 'OVERRIDE_OPT' from 'em' (/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/em.py) The Python package 'empy' must be installed and 'em' must not be installed since both packages share the same namespace
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_core/extension_point.py", line 166, in load_extension_points
    extension_type = load_extension_point(name, value, group)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_core/extension_point.py", line 207, in load_extension_point
    return EntryPoint(name, value, group).load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 171, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_powershell/shell/powershell.py", line 17, in <module>
    from colcon_core.shell.template import expand_template
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_core/shell/template/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    raise e from None
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_core/shell/template/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from em import OVERRIDE_OPT
ImportError: cannot import name 'OVERRIDE_OPT' from 'em' (/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/em.py) The Python package 'empy' must be installed and 'em' must not be installed since both packages share the same namespace

I've seen similar issues around and tried some troubleshooting. Just to clarify, my colcon-core is updated, the em library seems to be not installed and empy is on version 3.3.4
I'm at a loss, I would appreciate anything to identify the culprit and solve the issue. Thanks in advance.
EDIT: I'm running these commands to check em is not installed, in a terminal, after sourcing the ros installation
$ pip uninstall em
WARNING: Skipping em as it is not installed.

$ pip list
Package                              Version
------------------------------------ ----------------
action-msgs                          1.2.1
action-tutorials-interfaces          0.20.3
action-tutorials-py                  0.20.3
actionlib-msgs                       4.2.3
alabaster                            0.7.12
ament-cmake-test                     1.3.8
ament-copyright                      0.12.10
ament-cppcheck                       0.12.10
ament-cpplint                        0.12.10
ament-flake8                         0.12.10
ament-index-python                   1.4.0
ament-lint                           0.12.10
ament-lint-cmake                     0.12.10
ament-package                        0.14.0
ament-pep257                         0.12.10
ament-uncrustify                     0.12.10
ament-xmllint                        0.12.10
angles                               1.15.0
appdirs                              1.4.4
apturl                               0.5.2
argcomplete                          1.8.1
attrs                                21.2.0
Babel                                2.8.0
bcrypt                               3.2.0
beautifulsoup4                       4.10.0
beniget                              0.4.1
blinker                              1.4
bloom                                0.12.0
breezy                               3.2.1
Brlapi                               0.8.3
Brotli                               1.0.9
builtin-interfaces                   1.2.1
catkin-pkg                           1.0.0
catkin-pkg-modules                   1.0.0
certifi                              2020.6.20
chardet                              4.0.0
click                                8.0.3
colcon-argcomplete                   0.3.3
colcon-bash                          0.5.0
colcon-cd                            0.2.1
colcon-cmake                         0.2.28
colcon-common-extensions             0.3.0
colcon-core                          0.16.1
colcon-defaults                      0.2.8
colcon-devtools                      0.3.0
colcon-installed-package-information 0.2.1
colcon-library-path                  0.2.1
colcon-metadata                      0.2.5
colcon-mixin                         0.2.3
colcon-notification                  0.3.0
colcon-output                        0.2.13
colcon-override-check                0.0.1
colcon-package-information           0.4.0
colcon-package-selection             0.2.10
colcon-parallel-executor             0.3.0
colcon-pkg-config                    0.1.0
colcon-powershell                    0.4.0
colcon-python-setup-py               0.2.8
colcon-recursive-crawl               0.2.3
colcon-ros                           0.4.1
colcon-test-result                   0.3.8
colcon-zsh                           0.5.0
colorama                             0.4.4
command-not-found                    0.3
composition-interfaces               1.2.1
configobj                            5.0.6
cov-core                             1.15.0
coverage                             6.2
cryptography                         3.4.8
cupshelpers                          1.0
cv-bridge                            3.2.1
cycler                               0.11.0
dbus-python                          1.2.18
decorator                            4.4.2
defer                                1.0.6
demo-nodes-py                        0.20.3
Deprecated                           1.2.13
diagnostic-msgs                      4.2.3
distlib                              0.3.4
distro                               1.7.0
distro-info                          1.1+ubuntu0.2
docutils                             0.17.1
domain-coordinator                   0.10.0
dulwich                              0.20.31
duplicity                            0.8.21
empy                                 3.3.4
example-interfaces                   0.9.3
examples-rclpy-executors             0.15.1
examples-rclpy-minimal-action-client 0.15.1
examples-rclpy-minimal-action-server 0.15.1
examples-rclpy-minimal-client        0.15.1
examples-rclpy-minimal-publisher     0.15.1
examples-rclpy-minimal-service       0.15.1
examples-rclpy-minimal-subscriber    0.15.1
fastbencode                          0.0.5
fasteners                            0.14.1
fastimport                           0.9.14
flake8                               4.0.1
fonttools                            4.29.1
fs                                   2.4.12
future                               0.18.2
gast                                 0.5.2
geometry-msgs                        4.2.3
gpg                                  1.16.0
html5lib                             1.1
httplib2                             0.20.2
idna                                 3.3
image-geometry                       3.2.1
imagesize                            1.3.0
importlib-metadata                   4.6.4
iniconfig                            1.1.1
interactive-markers                  2.3.2
jeepney                              0.7.1
Jinja2                               3.0.3
keyring                              23.5.0
kiwisolver                           1.3.2
language-selector                    0.1
lark                                 1.1.1
laser-geometry                       2.4.0
launch                               1.0.5
launch-ros                           0.19.7
launch-testing                       1.0.5
launch-testing-ros                   0.19.7
launch-xml                           1.0.5
launch-yaml                          1.0.5
launchpadlib                         1.10.16
lazr.restfulclient                   0.14.4
lazr.uri                             1.0.6
lifecycle-msgs                       1.2.1
lockfile                             0.12.2
logging-demo                         0.20.3
louis                                3.20.0
lxml                                 4.8.0
lz4                                  3.1.3+dfsg
macaroonbakery                       1.3.1
Mako                                 1.1.3
map-msgs                             2.1.0
MarkupSafe                           2.0.1
matplotlib                           3.5.1
mccabe                               0.6.1
mercurial                            6.1.1
message-filters                      4.3.3
monotonic                            1.6
more-itertools                       8.10.0
mpi4py                               3.1.3
mpmath                               0.0.0
mutagen                              1.45.1
nav-msgs                             4.2.3
netifaces                            0.11.0
nose2                                0.9.2
notify2                              0.3
numpy                                1.21.5
oauthlib                             3.2.0
olefile                              0.46
osrf-pycommon                        2.0.2
packaging                            21.3
paramiko                             2.9.3
patiencediff                         0.2.1
pcl-msgs                             1.0.0
pendulum-msgs                        0.20.3
pexpect                              4.8.0
Pillow                               9.0.1
pip                                  24.0
pluggy                               0.13.0
ply                                  3.11
protobuf                             3.12.4
psutil                               5.9.0
ptyprocess                           0.7.0
py                                   1.10.0
pycairo                              1.20.1
pycodestyle                          2.8.0
pycryptodomex                        3.11.0
pycups                               2.0.1
pydocstyle                           6.1.1
pydot                                1.4.2
pyflakes                             2.4.0
PyGithub                             1.55
Pygments                             2.11.2
PyGObject                            3.42.1
PyJWT                                2.3.0
pymacaroons                          0.13.0
PyNaCl                               1.5.0
pyparsing                            2.4.7
PyQt5                                5.15.6
PyQt5-sip                            12.9.1
pyRFC3339                            1.1
pyros-genmsg                         0.5.8
pytest                               6.2.5
pytest-cov                           3.0.0
python-apt                           2.4.0+ubuntu3
python-dateutil                      2.8.1
python-debian                        0.1.43+ubuntu1.1
python-gitlab                        2.10.1
python-qt-binding                    1.1.2
pythran                              0.10.0
pytz                                 2022.1
pyxattr                              0.7.2
pyxdg                                0.27
PyYAML                               5.4.1
qt-dotgraph                          2.2.3
qt-gui                               2.2.3
qt-gui-cpp                           2.2.3
qt-gui-py-common                     2.2.3
quality-of-service-demo-py           0.20.3
rcl-interfaces                       1.2.1
rclpy                                3.3.12
rcutils                              5.1.5
reportlab                            3.6.8
requests                             2.25.1
requests-toolbelt                    0.9.1
resource-retriever                   3.1.1
rmw-dds-common                       1.6.0
roman                                3.3
ros2action                           0.18.9
ros2bag                              0.15.9
ros2cli                              0.18.9
ros2component                        0.18.9
ros2doctor                           0.18.9
ros2interface                        0.18.9
ros2launch                           0.19.7
ros2lifecycle                        0.18.9
ros2multicast                        0.18.9
ros2node                             0.18.9
ros2param                            0.18.9
ros2pkg                              0.18.9
ros2run                              0.18.9
ros2service                          0.18.9
ros2topic                            0.18.9
rosbag2-interfaces                   0.15.9
rosbag2-py                           0.15.9
rosdep                               0.23.0
rosdep-modules                       0.23.0
rosdistro                            0.9.0
rosdistro-modules                    0.9.0
rosgraph-msgs                        1.2.1
rosidl-adapter                       3.1.5
rosidl-cli                           3.1.5
rosidl-cmake                         3.1.5
rosidl-generator-c                   3.1.5
rosidl-generator-cpp                 3.1.5
rosidl-generator-dds-idl             0.8.1
rosidl-generator-py                  0.14.4
rosidl-parser                        3.1.5
rosidl-runtime-py                    0.9.3
rosidl-typesupport-c                 2.0.1
rosidl-typesupport-cpp               2.0.1
rosidl-typesupport-fastrtps-c        2.2.2
rosidl-typesupport-fastrtps-cpp      2.2.2
rosidl-typesupport-introspection-c   3.1.5
rosidl-typesupport-introspection-cpp 3.1.5
rospkg-modules                       1.5.1
rpyutils                             0.2.1
rqt-action                           2.0.1
rqt-bag                              1.1.4
rqt-bag-plugins                      1.1.4
rqt-console                          2.0.3
rqt-graph                            1.3.0
rqt-gui                              1.1.7
rqt-gui-py                           1.1.7
rqt-msg                              1.2.0
rqt-plot                             1.1.2
rqt-publisher                        1.5.0
rqt-py-common                        1.1.7
rqt-py-console                       1.0.2
rqt-reconfigure                      1.1.2
rqt-service-caller                   1.0.5
rqt-shell                            1.0.2
rqt-srv                              1.0.3
rqt-topic                            1.5.0
scipy                                1.8.0
SecretStorage                        3.3.1
sensor-msgs                          4.2.3
sensor-msgs-py                       4.2.3
setuptools                           69.5.1
shape-msgs                           4.2.3
six                                  1.16.0
snowballstemmer                      2.2.0
soupsieve                            2.3.1
Sphinx                               4.3.2
sros2                                0.10.4
ssh-import-id                        5.11
statistics-msgs                      1.2.1
std-msgs                             4.2.3
std-srvs                             4.2.3
stereo-msgs                          4.2.3
sympy                                1.9
systemd-python                       234
teleop-twist-keyboard                2.4.0
tf2-geometry-msgs                    0.25.6
tf2-kdl                              0.25.6
tf2-msgs                             0.25.6
tf2-py                               0.25.6
tf2-ros-py                           0.25.6
tf2-tools                            0.25.6
toml                                 0.10.2
topic-monitor                        0.20.3
trajectory-msgs                      4.2.3
turtlesim                            1.4.2
ubuntu-drivers-common                0.0.0
ubuntu-pro-client                    8001
ufoLib2                              0.13.1
ufw                                  0.36.1
unattended-upgrades                  0.1
unicodedata2                         14.0.0
unique-identifier-msgs               2.2.1
urllib3                              1.26.5
usb-creator                          0.3.7
vcstool                              0.3.0
vcstools                             0.1.42
visualization-msgs                   4.2.3
wadllib                              1.3.6
webencodings                         0.5.1
websockets                           9.1
wheel                                0.37.1
wrapt                                1.13.3
xdg                                  5
xkit                                 0.0.0
yt-dlp                               2022.4.8
zipp                                 1.0.0


How did you make sure that em is not installed?

@christophebedard check my edit

If your pip undeniably shows that em is not installed, but colcon undeniably says it is, I would assume you have multiple python exeutables and colcon uses a different one than pip. Can you check that?

One thing I notice is that the error happens when colcon tries to load the colcon_core.environment_variable.powershell_command extension, which is weird, because PowerShell is (usually) a Windows shell and you're on Ubuntu. Assuming you're not using PowerShell, try uninstalling the package that provides that extension (python3-colcon-powershell from apt or colcon-powershell from pip).
